# std::vector for pods

Tags: c++, vectors

I am learning c++ and read why we can't use realloc() in std::vector, but i think we can use realloc() for pods, so here is my attempt to write std::vector like class template specialized for PODs

```
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <type_traits>

namespace gupta {
namespace detail {
namespace podvector {
template <typename T> inline auto malloc(size_t elm_count) {
  return ::malloc(elm_count * sizeof(T));
}

template <typename T> inline auto realloc(void *old_block, size_t elm_count) {
  return ::realloc(old_block, elm_count * sizeof(T));
}
} // namespace podvector
} // namespace detail

template <typename PodType,
          typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_pod<PodType>::value>>
class podvector {
public:
  using value_type = PodType;
  using size_type = size_t;
  using pointer = value_type *;
  using const_value_pointer = const value_type *;

  ~podvector() {
    if (m_memory)
      free(m_memory);
  }

  podvector(size_type initial_size = 0) {
    alloc(initial_size);
    m_size = initial_size;
  }

  podvector(size_type initial_size, const value_type &value)
      : podvector(initial_size) {
    for (auto &v : *this)
      v = value;
  }

  podvector(const podvector &other) : podvector(other.m_size) {
    for (size_type i = 0; i < m_size; i++)
      m_memory[i] = other.m_memory[i];
  }

  podvector(const podvector &&other)
      : m_memory{std::move(other.m_memory)},
        m_capacity{std::move(other.m_capacity)}, m_size{
                                                     std::move(other.m_size)} {
    // other.m_memory = nullptr;
    other.alloc(0);
  }

  podvector &operator=(const podvector &rhs) {
    if (this != &rhs) {
      resize(rhs.m_size);
      for (size_type i = 0; i < rhs.m_size; i++)
        m_memory[i] = rhs[i];
    }
    return *this;
  }

  podvector &operator=(podvector &&rhs) {
    if (this != &rhs) {
      this->~podvector();
      m_memory = std::move(rhs.m_memory);
      m_capacity = std::move(rhs.m_capacity);
      m_size = std::move(rhs.m_size);
      // rhs.m_memory = nullptr;
      rhs.alloc(0);
    }
    return *this;
  }

  void resize(size_type new_size) {
    if (new_size > m_size)
      change_capacity(new_size);
    m_size = new_size;
  }

  void reserve(size_type new_capacity) {
    if (m_capacity < new_capacity)
      change_capacity(new_capacity);
  }

  void push_back(const value_type &new_elm) {
    if (m_size + 1 > m_capacity)
      change_capacity(std::min(m_capacity * 2, 1));
    m_memory[m_size++] = new_elm;
  }

  void pop_back() { m_size--; }

  auto size() const { return m_size; }
  auto capacity() const { return m_capacity; }
  pointer begin() { return m_memory; }
  const_value_pointer begin() const { return m_memory; }
  pointer end() { return m_memory + m_size; }
  const_value_pointer end() const { return m_memory + m_size; }
  value_type &operator[](size_type pos) { return m_memory[pos]; }
  const value_type &operator[](size_type pos) const { return m_memory[pos]; }

private:
  pointer m_memory;
  size_type m_size, m_capacity;
  void alloc(size_type capacity) {
    m_capacity = capacity;
    m_size = 0;
    m_memory =
        static_cast<pointer>(detail::podvector::malloc<value_type>(capacity));
    if (!m_memory)
      throw std::bad_alloc{};
  }
  void change_capacity(size_type new_capacity) {
    m_capacity = new_capacity;
    void *new_memory =
        detail::podvector::realloc<value_type>(m_memory, new_capacity);
    if (!new_memory)
      throw std::bad_alloc{};
    m_memory = static_cast<pointer>(new_memory);
  }
};

} // namespace gupta
```

Answer (score 7):

1. `malloc` and `realloc` live in `cstdlib`. `malloc.h` is not a standard header, neither in C++ nor in C, and should not be relied on in any case.
2. Also, you're missing `#include <utility>` for `std::move`.
3. Legacy C functionality, as everything else from the standard library, lives in the `std` namespace, if you include the corresponding `<cheader>` files. While you can also include the C standard headers via `<header.h>`, this is highly discouraged. With the first option, names may also exist in the global namespace, but this is not guaranteed and should not be relied on.
4. Your `malloc` and `realloc` functions need not be `inline`. In fact, `inline` does nothing here; remove it.
5. You don't need to check for null pointers when `free`ing memory. Passing a null pointer to `free` is always well defined and does nothing.
6. You don't need to move out all the data members from `other` in your move constructor. All of those members are trivial to copy, and have no special move behavior.
7. The move assignment operator invokes undefined behavior. You cannot just call the destructor of an object and then write to its members. Calling the destructor completely ends the lifetime of the object; afterwards, there's nothing there to write to. Furthermore, this is a kind of anti-pattern; in almost all cases, the move assignment operator should be implemented via the [copy-and-swap idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom).
8. `push_back` is broken. You call `change_capacity` with the result of `std::min(m_capacity * 2, 1)`, which is either 0 or 1, in any case. Most likely, you'd want to use `std::max` instead.
9. `if (m_size + 1 > m_capacity)` looks strange to my eyes. I would just write `if (m_size >= m_capacity)`.
10. `pop_back` should definitely return a value. It's not very useful otherwise.
11. Since you're going for what seems to be a std-like container interface, you should add a little more functionality. For one, you're missing some of the usual type definitions, such as `iterator` and `const_iterator`. Furthermore, some sort of `emplace` mechanism would be appropriate, as well as some way to clear the container and some functionality to shrink it, as well as some other things.
12. You should make sure that memory is properly initialized. As a user, I would expect that it's safe to access every element in bounds; however, you are not initializing memory at all, leaving that job to the user. I'd expect memory to be default- or zero-initialized; making use of `std::calloc` should do the trick (alternatively, you can also just `std::memset` the area).
13. I would make your `malloc` and `realloc` functions a little bit more useful. As of right now, the onus of checking whether allocation succeeded is put on the user of those functions, but in my opinion it would be much cleaner and safer to lift those functions to a "C++-safe" level, i.e. make them check the return value of the underlying allocation call directly and convert that into an exception directly.
14. `std::is_pod` is being deprecated, in accordance with the standard library moving away from the term POD as a whole. Also, the requirement that `T` must be a POD type is too strict; your vector will still work correctly if `T` is [trivial](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivial).

Comment: Re #10: `std::vector::pop_back` doesn't return a value, either. What would be nice, however, would be a `back()` member function that returns a reference to the last element in the `podvector`.

Comment: @hoffmale You're right. Still, why not fix the mistakes of the standard library while you're at it :P

Comment: Actually, I'm siding with the standard library: Removing the last element is a different operation than retrieving it (so it violates SRP), and if it isn't used by the caller `pop_back` just performs an unnecessary copy.

Comment: @hoffmale Well, in that case, the name `pop_back` is just badly chosen. A _pop_ operation should always return the popped value. If that's your stance, you should advocate for renaming the function to `remove_back`, or something along those lines.

Comment: If any `pop`-like member function were to return a value, no container could provide the strong exception guarantee mandated by the standard. This might not matter if the language is garbage collected and/or uses references only (basically forcing everybody to something similar to `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>`, where the assignment is `noexcept`), but this option is not available in C++. What would you do if `T` contains some resource (e.g. it's owning a pointer or file handle), but the assignment of the result from `pop`(or the like) throws an exception for some reason?

Comment: @hoffmale No, that's not what I'm saying. All I'm saying is that, if the function is named `pop`, it should return the removed value. If it doesn't, it should not be called `pop`, but `remove`, or something alike. In this case, implementing `pop` is fine because of the strict type requirements.

Answer (score 2):

### Memory Allocation Layer

Before looking at everything lets look at the memory allocation layer.

```
#include <malloc.h>

namespace gupta {
namespace detail {
namespace podvector {
template <typename T> inline auto malloc(size_t elm_count) {
  return ::malloc(elm_count * sizeof(T));
}

template <typename T> inline auto realloc(void *old_block, size_t elm_count) {
  return ::realloc(old_block, elm_count * sizeof(T));
}
} // namespace podvector
} // namespace detail

....
private:
  void alloc(size_type capacity) {
    m_capacity = capacity;
    m_size = 0;
    m_memory =
        static_cast<pointer>(detail::podvector::malloc<value_type>(capacity));
    if (!m_memory)
      throw std::bad_alloc{};
  }
  void change_capacity(size_type new_capacity) {
    m_capacity = new_capacity;
    void *new_memory =
        detail::podvector::realloc<value_type>(m_memory, new_capacity);
    if (!new_memory)
      throw std::bad_alloc{};
    m_memory = static_cast<pointer>(new_memory);
  }
```

Lets just say that `<malloc.h>` is not a valid header. You should probably be using `<cstdlib>` (this is C++ so prefer the C++ headers) which puts all the function in the standard namespace. So your use of `::malloc()` and `::realloc()` are wrong as they are not necessarily in the global namespace (you just happen to get lucky).

You do the memory allocation in your `gupta::detail::podvector` namespace but leave the checking for null to your vector class. Using `Separation of Concerns` we should really be doing all the memory handling (including checking for failed allocation) in your memory functions not inside your vector.

Also why are you `static_cast` the result in the vector. Would it not be easier to cast the type in the allocation routines so that you return the correct type.

Though your use of `static_cast` is correct this is the kind of thing I would want other developers to have a critical look at to make sure I got it correct. Thus I would have used `reinterpret_cast<>()` to make people stop and think to make sure cast is correct.

There is a bug in your current code. A std::vector always makes sure all members are in a specific state after initialization. You don't do this. Your main constructor simply calls `alloc()` then sets the size. Since alloc simply calls `std::malloc()` the underlying memory is not in any specific state. Thus I would use `std::calloc()` to make sure the memory returned is in a standard state.

```
template <typename T>
T* new_malloc(size_t elm_count) {
    auto tmp = std::calloc(elm_count, sizeof(T));
    if (tmp == nullptr) {
        throw std::bad_alloc("PLOP");
    }
    return reinterpret_cast<T*>(tmp);
}

template <typename T>
T* new_realloc(void *old_block, size_t elm_count) {
    auto tmp = std::realloc(old_block, elm_count * sizeof(T));
    if (tmp == nullptr) {
        throw std::bad_alloc("PLIP");
    }
    return reinterpret_cast<T*>(tmp);
}

...
private:
  void alloc(size_type capacity) {
      m_capacity = capacity;
      m_size     = 0;
      m_memory   = detail::podvector::new_malloc<value_type>(capacity));
  }
  void change_capacity(size_type new_capacity) {
      m_capacity = new_capacity;
      m_memory   = detail::podvector::new_realloc<value_type>(m_memory, new_capacity);
  }
```

### Specialization for POD

If you want to specialize for POD. You don't need to customize the whole vector. You just need to specialize the allocation method used by the vector.

You do need to keep it in mind for a couple of functions (but I don't think you need to do anything special).

```
private:
  // POD Data
  typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_pod<PodType>::value>>::value_type
  alloc(size_type capacity) {
      m_capacity = capacity;
      m_size     = 0;
      m_memory   = detail::podvector::new_malloc<value_type>(capacity));
  }
  typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_pod<PodType>::value>>::value_type
  change_capacity(size_type new_capacity) {
      m_capacity = new_capacity;
      m_memory   = detail::podvector::new_realloc<value_type>(m_memory, new_capacity);
  }


  // Any other Data
  typename std::enable_if_t<!std::is_pod<PodType>::value>>::value_type
  alloc(size_type capacity) {
      m_capacity = capacity;
      m_size     = 0;
      m_memory   = ::operator new(sizeof(T) * m_capacity);
  }
  typename std::enable_if_t<!std::is_pod<PodType>::value>>::value_type
  change_capacity(size_type new_capacity) {
      podvector<T>  tmpBuffer(newCapacity);

      for(loop = 0; loop < m_size; ++loop) {
          tmpBuffer.push_back(std::move(m_memory[loop]));
      }
      tmpBuffer.swap(*this);
  }
```

Comment: I'm more in favor of using`if constexpr` for the specializations, makes the code easier to read

Comment: @JVApen Do you have a link to an example or description?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51659883/2466431 should indicate the idea

Comment: @JVApen I have seen that once before. But I have never used it. I will need to experiment. I have some code reviews coming up where this may help.